# How to enable Basic Authentication for WebDAV on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, webdav, basic-authentication

Previously I used to be able to access external data from an `http://` URL using only Basic Authentication (Username / Password) as text file from within an Excel (2003 version) on a Windows XP Professional laptop.

I recently bought a new Windows 8 laptop, running Excel 2010 and now I can't get access to the same external data. Apparently Basic Authentication for WebDAV on Windows 8 is not by default enabled.

Searching the internet I only find solutions to enable Basic Authentication for WebDAV for windows version older than Windows 8.

Who has a "simple" solution to resolve this? Note that I'm not a developer, just a user.

Answer (score 8):

Ran into the same issue.  Found a solution here, even though the article is for Windows 7.  It works the same.

http://www.yeehawup.com/2011/07/mapping-a-network-drive-to-webdav-share-in-windows-7/

The relevant information from the blog post (which I'm shocked is still up after four years) is to set the registry DWORD

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\
Parameters\BasicAuthLevel
```

to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Microsoft documentation for the [WebDav redirector](https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-webdav/using-the-webdav-redirector#004) including the registry keys. Basically 2 lets you force allow Basic Auth without HTTPS (which is a bad choice, don't do it).